# How can I fix Wifi with my Broadcom BCM43142 card?

Tags: wifi, broadcom

I use Fedora 21 on my new Lenovo Yoga 2 11" laptop. I have a Broadcom BCM43142 wireless card:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at b0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

And the only driver I've been able to get to work is `wl`. It won't work with the `b43` driver.

I can connect to a network, but then the connection is either painfully, painfully slow, or hangs on connecting, or cuts out after a minute or so. Wifi works fine on Windows. How can I get this to work?

Comment: It seems that your card is only supported by wl, but see http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Supported_devices for details.

Comment: @njsg, Yes, I figured that out. But what I want to know is: how can I get my card to work correctly, using the `wl` driver?

Comment: Best way to fix Broadcom Wireless issues on Notebooks with Linux/FreeBSD/OpenBSD is to replace with a Intel or Atheros card... </joke>

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the `wl` driver properly installed, from the console try:

```
sudo rmmod -f ideapad_laptop
```

That may get things going. If not (or to blacklist the module across reboots), try:

```
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" >> /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf
```

and reboot.

Apparently there may be conflicts with the ideapad_laptop module trying to manage the wlan at the same time as the wifi driver.

Comment: Also unloading the `bcma` module which conflict with `wl` module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if this is the same as my bug, where it works for a bit and then goes very slow and you need to reset it:

[Debian Jessie Wireless Driver Broadcom Restart (rmmod modprobe) BCM43142 [14e4:4365]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259098/debian-jessie-wireless-driver-broadcom-restart-rmmod-modprobe-bcm43142-14e44)